# How can I set a format for each column when displaying my table?

Tags: matlab, format, numeric, display

My table only contains numerical data. I have format set to long and all of the variables are of that type. How can tell MATLAB to display each column differently? i.e column 1 as type long with 15 decimal digit precision, column 2 in scientific notation with 4 decimal precision, etc?

Comment: Display them *where*?

Comment: Either in the command window or saved in pdf format. The output should be able to be used in a word document.

Comment: See: [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)